# How can I integrate categorized content from an external web service into Joomla 1.5?

Tags: php, joomla

I'm working on a Joomla 1.5 site where products and categories come from a SOAP web service.

The navigation starts by with selecting a category of products. These categories and products come from the web service. After selecting a category the web service returns a list of products. From there the user can select a product and it must open a page with that product's details. These products and categories do not have to be content items within the Joomla admin, they just need to be a part of the frontend site.

An example of the navigation using the same web service is [here](http://www.clevelandbrothers.com/cat_equipment.php).

I already have the classes and code needed to get the products from the web service, however I'm quite unsure how to make it fit in Joomla. I'm a beginner when it comes to Joomla component development.  Is anyone aware of any bridges or similar components that work in a same way?

Comment: If you don't find an extension in JED you can create your own component. Look here: http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_simple_component for more details

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the JED (Joomla Extensions Directory)
http://extensions.joomla.org/search?q=SOAP

I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for, but there are literally thousands of things that may help!  Lots of times if you're after something... someone else has had the same desire - and often there's a component/plugin/module to help!